# Make a Button/View appear on Scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I wondered, how to achieve following:
There are many apps out there, having some editText view or similar on top of a layout and another view like webview or listview below of that.
For example, in the google chrome browser we got the URL bar at the top of the parent, and below of that the webview. Now when scrolling down, of course, the URL bar disappears. But when swiping a bit up, one can see that the url bar is back even though I didn't scroll up the view to the very top. 
How is this called, could you tell me some site where this function is explained?

Same thing in the google now app: 
The search bar is at the top of the layout, below of that the listview with the cards.
When scrolling down the listview, the search bar disappears. But when slightly scrolling back up, the search bar appears again.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are describing a pattern known as the "Quick Return." Check out [this article](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/an-emerging-ui-pattern-quick-return.html) that describes the pattern and links to an implementation.